# Correct way to decrement an AtomicLong by a certain delta

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

Given an `AtomicLong` object, what is the right way to decrement the value by a delta?

**Option 1**

```
AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong(0L);

public void decrementCount(long decrementBy) {
       count.getAndUpdate(l->count.get() - decrementBy);
}
```

**Option 2**

```
AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong(0L);

public void decrementCount(long decrementBy) {
       count.getAndAdd(-decrementBy);
}
```

While both give the desired result, I want to understand under what circumstance will they not represent the desired behavior i.e to decrement a long value atomically? (One drawback of the second approach for example could be the negative sign causing some bit overflow but I am not sure if that's true)

Comment: @Hulk Thanks for the response. Yes it works with other values as well. This code runs inside a method called by multiple threads. Editted to make it more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> count.getAndUpdate(l->count.get() - decrementBy);
> ```

This doesn't work atomically. `getAndUpdate` works roughly like this:

```
long getAndUpdate(LongUnaryOperator op) {
  long current;
  long newValue;
  do {
    current = this.get();
    newValue = op.apply(current);
  while (!compareAndSet(current, newValue));
  return current;
}
```

By re-reading `count.get()` inside the lambda, you're reading the value of the `AtomicLong` *then*, which might be different to the value of `current` that it was passed, if some other thread updated the `AtomicLong` in between; you'd then update based on the updated value, not `current`.

Use the value you are passed in `l`:

```
count.getAndUpdate(l->l - decrementBy);
```

But `getAndAdd(-decrementBy)` is easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are there any bit overflow issues when negating the `decrementBy` variable once can expect?

Comment: "Are there any bit overflow issues" exactly the same overflow issues as if you were working with an `int`.

Comment: Noted. This would make the first approach of using `getAndUpdate` a better choice; however, if my long overflows, I am doomed anyway?

Comment: "This would make the first approach of using getAndUpdate a better choice" why?

Comment: `decrementBy` as an input may be fine on it's own. When negated using `-decrementBy`, aren't we exposing it to bit oveflow issues? `AtomicLong` or not, avoiding negating a variable is a better choice? (My computer science a bit rusty so forgive my negligence if this is not making sense)

Comment: The only way you'd have issues with negating `decrementBy` is if it is equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. You have exactly the same overflow issues otherwise.

Comment: Right. So given that there is a possibility of an issue (Even though a remote possibility), it is better to use `getAndUpdate` option?

Comment: "equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`" I mean `Long.MIN_VALUE`. I thought it was about `AtomicInteger`, not `AtomicLong`.

Answer (score 3):

Your second approach is correct, as [`getAndAdd`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#getAndAdd(long))):

> Atomically adds the given value to the current value

```
AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong(0L);
count.getAndAdd(-decrementBy);
```

Your first approach is slightly off, because it uses `count.get()`, when ["The function should be side-effect-free"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#getAndUpdate(java.util.function.LongUnaryOperator)), and a `LongUnaryOperator` i.e. ideally only use the Long-value it is given as a parameter. While reading an atomic value may not strictly count as a side-effect, it is not necessary and needlessly makes the update non-atomic.

Comment: Yes. I am using getAndAdd and passing it the negative value of the decrementBy variable. My quesiton had a typo which I corrected. The question is - Which approach will result in side effects that I am not aware of at this point in time..

Comment: "Your second approach is slightly off, because it uses count.get()"  - do oyu mean my first approach?

Comment: @Ping yes. updated.

Comment: I wouldn't count reading a value as a side effect. It's certainly better if it is _pure_, though.

Comment: It's not just more complicated. Calling `count.get()` is incorrect and makes the update non-atomic, allowing incorrect results when other threads are incrementing and decrementing at the same time.

Comment: @MattTimmermans you are right. Updated.

Answer (score -1):

I think that this class, has all methods prepared to:

> The AtomicLong class provides you with a long variable which can be
> read and written atomically, and which also contains advanced atomic
> operations

is depending on the order that you want use before and after that update or update first and read after. You have arpopiate methods for incrementing and decrementing:

```
    addAndGet()
    getAndAdd()
    getAndIncrement()
    incrementAndGet()
    getAndDecrement()
    decrementAndGet()
```

then something like this:

```
AtomicLong atomicLong = new AtomicLong(22);

System.out.println(atomicLong.getAndAdd(-1));
System.out.println(atomicLong.addAndGet(-1));
```